# Why is Paste event attached on document not working on IE?

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard, paste

I'm trying to catch paste event (ctrl+v) and copy content from clipboard. If I attach paste event to document, it's not working on IE (v11), though it's working on chrome. If I however attach event to element with `contenteditable='true'` then it's working on IE too.

Any ideas why is that?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div id='editableDiv' contenteditable='true'>Paste</div>
  <script>
    function handlePaste (e) {
        var clipboardData, pastedData;

        // Stop data actually being pasted into div
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get pasted data via clipboard API
        clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
        pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');

        // Do whatever with pasteddata
        alert(pastedData);
    }
    //document.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
    document.getElementById('editableDiv').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works for ie:

```
document.getElementById('editableDiv').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```

While this does not:

```
document.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```

**Edit**

It would seem IE supports this event only on editable elements.

Comment: could this be contributing to the problem? https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/535